# .NET compact framework missing assemblies?

Tags: .net, compact-framework

I'm using NPanday to build a c# project to the .NET 3.5 compact framework. NPanday expects `System.Windows.Forms.DataGrid` and `Microsoft.Transactions.Bridge` to be found in the compact framework but these are missing in my install.

On another computer I notice that these 2 assemblies do exist in .NET 2.0 compact. Should I copy them to my 3.5 directory? Where are these assemblies usually located?

Comment: I don't think either Microsoft.Transactions.Bridge or DataGrid are supported in Compact Framework, check MSDN to see if they are in the supported versions.

Comment: @Mike Miller I looked at the [DataGrid class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagrid%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) page with framework version = 3.5 and it says ".NET Compact Framework. Supported in: 3.5, 2.0, 1.0" so it seems like it should be there. I can't find anything that says Microsoft.Transactions.Bridge is supported though.

Comment: Is this still an issue? May be it is easy to fix in NPanday...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DataGrid is supported, though in a limited form.  [See this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagrid_members%28v=VS.90%29.aspx).  Only those items with a device icon by them are supported.  None of the Microsoft.Transactions namespace is supported in the CF.

Comment: I guess this is as close to an answer as I'm going to get. Looks like a bug with NPanday.

Answer (score 0):

They moved System.Windows.Forms.DataGrid back into the main .NET 3.5 assemblies, so just remove the reverence to the System.Windows.Forms.DataGrid.dll, and it should build fine.